# How to print variables using Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#

The following code demonstrates the use of the sleep() method for making a thread pause for a specific period of time.

When I run this code :-

```
class Program
{
    class ThreadCreationProgram
    {
        public static void CallToChildThread()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Child thread starts");

            // the thread is paused for 5000 milliseconds
            int sleepfor = 5000;

            Console.WriteLine("Child Thread Paused for {0} seconds");
            Thread.Sleep(sleepfor);
            Console.WriteLine("Child thread resumes");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadStart childref = new ThreadStart(CallToChildThread);
            Console.WriteLine("In Main: Creating the Child thread");
            Thread childThread = new Thread(childref);
            childThread.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**I  get this output-**

```
In Main: Creating the child thread
Child thread starts
Child thread paused for <0> seconds
Child thread resumes
```

**But what i expect is :-**

```
In Main: Creating the child thread
Child thread starts
Child thread paused for <5> seconds
Child thread resumes
```

How can I do it any suggestions?

Comment: The key thing here in my mind is to ask yourself why you expected that output? Look at the line, think hard about what it does and you should have been able to come to the conclusion that the answers here told you on your own.

Comment: Next i will think hard before asking @Chris

Comment: Learning good debugging techniques is absolutely vital to get by in programming. As you can see we are always happy to help answer questions though so don't let what I said put you off asking in the future if you can't work it out on your own. :)

Comment: Next time i will correct my mistake @Chris

Comment: You don't have `<` or `>` in your string at all, so there is no way those could be in either the actual or expected output.

Comment: no i got the actual output:In Main: Creating the child thread

Child thread starts

Child thread paused for <0> seconds

Child thread resumes And After making changes Console.WriteLine("Child Thread Paused for {0} seconds", (sleepfor/1000).ToString());  i got the expected output   In Main: Creating the child thread

Child thread starts

Child thread paused for <5> seconds

Child thread resumes

Comment: you should run the exact code @crashmstr

Comment: @crashmstr why should i lie ? or make you believe its none of my business if you don't believe

Comment: If I run that exact code, I see `Child Thread Paused for {0} seconds`, not `Child thread paused for <0> seconds`. I'm not accusing you of *lying*, I'm suggesting you've copied something incorrectly in the code and/or the outputs. Also, with the change you say you made, the output would be `Child Thread Paused for 5 seconds` and not `Child Thread Paused for <5> seconds`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is where you mistake is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Child Thread Paused for {0} seconds", (sleepfor/1000).ToString());
```

You didn't specify where the value for the `{0}` comes from.

Also you need to calculate from milliseconds to seconds, thats why `/1000`

Comment: Thanks @Heenne for your suggestion its working as expected now

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see `Child thread passed for <5> seconds`, then you need to print exactly that.

Below is the problem line of your code

```
Console.WriteLine("Child Thread Paused for {0} seconds");
```

This should be

```
Console.WriteLine("Child Thread Paused for <{0}> seconds", sleepfor/1000);
```

As you notice, you haven't specified the parameter `{0}` in your call. You can refer to the documentation on [`Console.WriteLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Note that `Console.WriteLine` follows the formatting rules set by [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906224(v=vs.110).aspx). The [format string rules can be seen here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting).

In the newer syntax you don't need to use the place holders like `{0}` but can embed the expression itself in the string, called [Interpolated Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings)

```
Console.WriteLine($"Child Thread Paused for <{sleepfor/1000}> seconds");
```

Comment: Thanks @Vikhram for your suggestion its working as expected now

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Child Thread Paused for <{0}> seconds", sleepfor/1000);
```

or C# 6 approach:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Child Thread Paused for <{sleepfor/1000}> seconds");
```

Comment: Thanks @BladeMaster